# Генератор поролей на VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Скажите, вот у меня есть TextBox1, TextBox2 и кнопка Button1. При нажатии на кнопку, программа считывает значение из TextBox2 (кол-во символов в пароле). Затем генерирует пароль из этого списка.

> QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890

Далее выводил его в TextBox1.

Comment: И что? Какой вопрос?

Comment: Как это сделать? Какой код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, ты хочешь узнать, как программа генерирует пароль?..
И что тут сложного?..
Можно сделать так: в цикле for (цикл повторяется столько раз, сколько символов в будущем пароле) выбирается случайный (random'ный) символ из предложенной строки допустимых в пароле символов и прибавляется к строке с паролем (в конец строки, конечно). Точно не знаю, как это выглядит на VB, но это просто.
Возможно есть другие способы, но и этот способ тоже позволяет создавать уникальный пароль... Вот только символы не должны повторяться. Для этого можно проверять (например, с помощью функции поиска символа в строке), есть ли уже такой символ в нашей строке-пароле, и если нет - добавлять символ, а если есть - повторно выбирать случайный символ из строки допустимых символов.